# PHP for loop not starting at 0

Tags: php

So, I have code like this at the start of a bigger set of loops

```
for ($k=1;$k<=60-$jrow['blocks'];$k += $jrow['blocks'])
{
for ($j=0;$j=(count($sarray)-1);$j++)
{
```

The size of $sarray is 2

Now, when I apply this:

```
if (isset($j) AND $k == 1)
{
echo "<h1>".$j."</h1>";
}
```

I get an output of 1. Now clearly $k is still in it's first iteration, but it seems like $j has somehow skipped onto it's second and isn't starting at 0. What am I doing wrong.

Whole code, if required:

```
for ($k=1;$k<=60-$jrow['blocks'];$k += $jrow['blocks'])
{
for ($j=0;$j=(count($sarray)-1);$j++)
{
if (isset($j) AND $k == 1)
{
echo "<h1>".$j."</h1>";
}
for ($l=$k;$l=($k+$jrow['blocks']-1);$l++)
{
$uid = $sarray[$j];
$staffquery = $hsdbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userID = :uid");
$staffquery->bindParam(':uid',$uid);
$staffquery->execute();
$staffid = $staffquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (isset($staffid['userid']))
{
echo "<h1>staff query orking</h1>";
die();
}
if ($staffid['complevel'] > $jrow['complevel'])
{
if ($l + ($jrow['blocks'] - 1) < 20 * $i)
{
$schedquery = $hsdbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE slot = :sn");
$schedquery->bindParam(':sn',$l);
$schedquery->execute();
$schedrow = $schedquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($schedrow['jobID'] == 0)
{
for ($m=$l;$m=($l+$jrow['blocks']-1);$m++)
{
$setquery = $hsdbc->prepare("UPDATE schedule SET jobID = :jid WHERE userID=:uid AND slot = :sn");
$setquery->bindParam(':jid',$jrow['jobID']);
$setquery->bindParam(':uid',$staffid['userid']);
$setquery->bindParam(':sn',$m);
$setquery->execute();
}
$cjobquery = $hsdbc->prepare("UPDATE job SET statusID = 1 WHERE jobID = :jid");
$cjobquery->bindParam(':jid',$jrow['jobID']);
$cjobquery->execute();
Break 6;
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: `j=(count($sarray)-1)` in your second for loop

Comment: `$j=(count($sarray)-1)` — This value will always be constant. Most likely, this would result in an infinite loop. You want to use `==` instead.

Comment: More like `<=`, don't you think ?

Comment: **Debugging Tip**: These things are often easier to spot if you format your code better. I didn't see that error until I copied & pasted to code and started to reformat it so I could read it. Here's one suggested [set of coding standards](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html).

Comment: Does anyone know why $l = $k in the third loop doesn't work for the initial expression?

Answer (score 0):

```
$j = (count($sarray)-1)
```

this is an assignment, use the `==` operator for equality comparison, or `<=`, `>=` for order comparison.

Comment: Ah jesus, you're right. I knew it would be something obvious. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write. This is probably a typo.

```
for ($j=0;$j<=(count($sarray)-1);$j++)
```